# Adding a TextField to a program

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, layout-manager

I am making a better version of an application that was given to me. I still need to have the same components as the program that was given to me, I just need to reorganize it. I was also told not to copy any of the original code and do it from scratch. The first screenshot shows the textfield I need to add to my program from the original program. The second screenshot is my program. I am not sure if a JTextField would be best for this. My code is below. I have tried to add a JTextField with a JLabel and center it but when I run the program it covers everything else in the program and only shows a little white box.

[image: original]
[image: my program]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class TestApplication implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JLabel input = new JLabel();
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
    frame.setTitle("RBA Test Application");
    frame.add(input);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

// Make all necessary buttons
    JButton next = new JButton("Next");

    JButton save = new JButton("Save");
    JButton save2 = new JButton("Save");
    JButton save3 = new JButton("Save");
    JButton save4 = new JButton("Save");

    JButton aok = new JButton("OK");
    JButton bok = new JButton("OK");
    JButton cok = new JButton("OK");

    JButton acancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton bcancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton ccancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton dcancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton ecancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton fcancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton gcancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    JButton hcancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    //Make the drop down lists
    String[] baudrates = {"57600", "115200", "128000", "256000"};
    JComboBox baudlist = new JComboBox(baudrates);

    String[] baudrates2 = {"57600", "115200", "128000", "256000"};
    JComboBox baudlist2 = new JComboBox(baudrates2);

    String[] bytesizes = {"7", "8"};
    JComboBox bytelist = new JComboBox(bytesizes);

    String[] bytesizes2 = {"7", "8"};
    JComboBox bytelist2 = new JComboBox(bytesizes2);

    String[] stopbit = {"1", "2"};
    JComboBox stoplist = new JComboBox(stopbit);

    String[] stopbit2 = {"1", "2"};
    JComboBox stoplist2 = new JComboBox(stopbit2);

    String[] flows = {"None", "Hardware","Xon", "Xoff"};
    JComboBox flowlist = new JComboBox(flows);

    String[] flows2 = {"None", "Hardware","Xon", "Xoff"};
    JComboBox flowlist2 = new JComboBox(flows2);

    String[] paritys = {"None", "Even", "Odd"};
    JComboBox paritylist = new JComboBox(paritys);

    String[] paritys2 = {"None", "Even", "Odd"};
    JComboBox paritylist2 = new JComboBox(paritys2);

    //Make all necessary labels
    JLabel cardLabel = new JLabel("Card Number: ");
    JLabel expLabel = new JLabel("Exp. Date (MM/YY): ");
    JLabel cvvLabel = new JLabel("CVV: ");
    JLabel ipLabel = new JLabel("IP Address: ");
    JLabel connectLabel = new JLabel("Connect Time: ");
    JLabel sendLabel = new JLabel("Send Time Out: ");
    JLabel receiveLabel = new JLabel("Receive Time Out: ");
    JLabel portLabel = new JLabel("Port: ");
    JLabel baudrate = new JLabel("Baud Rate: ");
    JLabel bytesize = new JLabel("Byte Size: ");
    JLabel stopbits = new JLabel("Stop Bits: ");
    JLabel flow = new JLabel("Flow Con..: ");
    JLabel parity = new JLabel("Parity: ");
    JLabel stoLabel = new JLabel("Send Time Out: ");
    JLabel rtoLabel = new JLabel("Receive Time Out: ");
    JLabel portLabel2 = new JLabel("Port: ");
    JLabel baudrate2 = new JLabel("Baud Rate: ");
    JLabel bytesize2 = new JLabel("Byte Size: ");
    JLabel stopbits2 = new JLabel("Stop Bits: ");
    JLabel flow2 = new JLabel("Flow Con..: ");
    JLabel parity2 = new JLabel("Parity: ");
    JLabel stoLabel2 = new JLabel("Send Time Out: ");
    JLabel rtoLabel2 = new JLabel("Receive Time Out: ");
    JLabel portLabel3 = new JLabel("Port: ");
    JLabel vendor = new JLabel("Vendor ID: ");
    JLabel product = new JLabel("Product ID: ");
    JLabel stoLabel3 = new JLabel("Send Time Out: ");
    JLabel rtoLabel3 = new JLabel("Receive Time Out: ");
    JLabel amountLabel = new JLabel("Amount: ");
    JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Display Text: ");

    //Make all necessary TextFields 
    JTextField card = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField expDate = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField cvv = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField ip = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField ct = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField rto = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField sto = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField port = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField sendto = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField reto = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField comport = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField sendto2 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField reto2 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField comport2 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField vendorid = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField productid = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField sendtime = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField receiveto = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField amountbox = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField textBox = new JTextField(10);


    //Add components to the panels
    final JPanel ethernetSettings = new JPanel();
    ethernetSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 2));
    ethernetSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    ethernetSettings.add(ipLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(ip);
    ethernetSettings.add(connectLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(ct);
    ethernetSettings.add(receiveLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(rto);
    ethernetSettings.add(sendLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(sto);
    ethernetSettings.add(portLabel);
    ethernetSettings.add(port);
    ethernetSettings.add(save);
    ethernetSettings.add(ecancel);

    final JPanel usbHIDSettings = new JPanel();
    usbHIDSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2));
    usbHIDSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    usbHIDSettings.add(vendor);
    usbHIDSettings.add(vendorid);
    usbHIDSettings.add(product);
    usbHIDSettings.add(productid);
    usbHIDSettings.add(stoLabel3);
    usbHIDSettings.add(sendtime);
    usbHIDSettings.add(rtoLabel3);
    usbHIDSettings.add(receiveto);
    usbHIDSettings.add(save4);
    usbHIDSettings.add(hcancel);

    final JPanel usbCDCSettings = new JPanel();
    usbCDCSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 2));
    usbCDCSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    usbCDCSettings.add(baudrate2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(baudlist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(bytesize2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(bytelist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(stopbits2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(stoplist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(flow2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(flowlist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(parity2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(paritylist);
    usbCDCSettings.add(stoLabel2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(sendto2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(rtoLabel2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(reto2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(portLabel3);
    usbCDCSettings.add(comport2);
    usbCDCSettings.add(save3);
    usbCDCSettings.add(gcancel);

    final JPanel rsSettings = new JPanel();
    rsSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 2));
    rsSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    rsSettings.add(baudrate);
    rsSettings.add(baudlist2);
    rsSettings.add(bytesize);
    rsSettings.add(bytelist2);
    rsSettings.add(stopbits);
    rsSettings.add(stoplist2);
    rsSettings.add(flow);
    rsSettings.add(flowlist2);
    rsSettings.add(parity);
    rsSettings.add(paritylist2);
    rsSettings.add(stoLabel);
    rsSettings.add(sendto);
    rsSettings.add(rtoLabel);
    rsSettings.add(reto);
    rsSettings.add(portLabel2);
    rsSettings.add(comport);
    rsSettings.add(save2);
    rsSettings.add(fcancel);

    JRadioButton ethernet = new JRadioButton("Ethernet");
    ethernet.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JDialog esettings = new JDialog(frame);
            esettings.setTitle("Ethernet Settings");
            esettings.add(ethernetSettings);
            esettings.setSize(400, 400);
            esettings.pack();
            esettings.setVisible(true);

        }
    });


    JRadioButton rs = new JRadioButton("RS232");
    rs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JDialog rsettings = new JDialog(frame);
            rsettings.setTitle("RS232 Settings");
            rsettings.add(rsSettings);
            rsettings.pack();
            rsettings.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

    JRadioButton usbcdc = new JRadioButton("USB_CDC");
    usbcdc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JDialog usbc = new JDialog(frame);
            usbc.setTitle("USB_CDC Settings");
            usbc.add(usbCDCSettings);
            usbc.setSize(400, 400);
            usbc.pack();
            usbc.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

    JRadioButton usbhid = new JRadioButton("USB_HID");
    usbhid.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JDialog usbh = new JDialog(frame);
            usbh.setTitle("USB_HID Settings");
            usbh.add(usbHIDSettings);
            usbh.setSize(400, 400);
            usbh.pack();
            usbh.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

    final JPanel PortSettings = new JPanel();
    PortSettings.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4));
    PortSettings.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    PortSettings.add(ethernet);
    PortSettings.add(rs);
    PortSettings.add(usbcdc);
    PortSettings.add(usbhid);
    PortSettings.add(next);
    PortSettings.add(bcancel);

    final JPanel accountPanel = new JPanel();
    accountPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));
    accountPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    accountPanel.add(cardLabel);
    accountPanel.add(card);
    accountPanel.add(expLabel);
    accountPanel.add(expDate);
    accountPanel.add(cvvLabel);
    accountPanel.add(cvv);
    accountPanel.add(bok);
    accountPanel.add(ccancel);

    JRadioButton apprve = new JRadioButton("Approve");
    JRadioButton decline = new JRadioButton("Decline");


    final JPanel apprvordecl = new JPanel();
    apprvordecl.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
    apprvordecl.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    apprvordecl.add(apprve);
    apprvordecl.add(decline);
    apprvordecl.add(textLabel);
    apprvordecl.add(textBox);
    apprvordecl.add(aok);
    apprvordecl.add(acancel);

    final JPanel amountPanel = new JPanel();
    amountPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    amountPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    amountPanel.add(amountLabel);
    amountPanel.add(amountbox);
    amountPanel.add(cok);
    amountPanel.add(dcancel);

    JButton initialize = new JButton("Initialize");

    JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");

    JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");

    JButton shutdown = new JButton("Shut Down");


    JButton portsettings = new JButton("Port Settings");
     portsettings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog port = new JDialog(frame);
                port.setTitle("Port Settings");
                port.setSize(400, 400);
                port.add(PortSettings);
                port.pack();
                port.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    JButton online = new JButton("Go Online");

    JButton offline = new JButton("Go Offline");

    JButton status = new JButton("Status");

    JButton reboot = new JButton("Reboot");


    JButton account = new JButton("Account");
     account.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog accountDialog = new JDialog(frame);
                accountDialog.setTitle("Account");
                accountDialog.setSize(400, 400);
                accountDialog.add(accountPanel);
                accountDialog.pack();
                accountDialog.setVisible(true);



            }
        });

    JButton amount = new JButton("Amount");
     amount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog amount2 = new JDialog(frame);
                amount2.setTitle("Amount");
                amount2.setSize(400, 400);
                amount2.add(amountPanel);
                amount2.pack();
                amount2.setVisible(true);



            }
        });

    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");


    JButton approvordecl = new JButton("Approve / Decline");
     approvordecl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog apprv = new JDialog(frame);
                apprv.setTitle("Approve / Decline");
                apprv.setSize(400, 400);
                apprv.add(apprvordecl);
                apprv.pack();
                apprv.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    JButton test = new JButton("Test Button #1");

    JButton testing = new JButton("Test Button #2");

    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    JRadioButton button2 = new JRadioButton("Radio Button");

    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Check Box");

    JCheckBox checkbox2 = new JCheckBox("Check Box");

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(usbhid);
    group.add(usbcdc);
    group.add(ethernet);
    group.add(rs);

    ButtonGroup approvegroup = new ButtonGroup();
    approvegroup.add(apprve);
    approvegroup.add(decline);


    JPanel testPanel = new JPanel();
    testPanel.add(button);
    testPanel.add(button2);
    testPanel.add(checkbox2);

    JPanel posPanel = new JPanel();
    posPanel.add(test);
    posPanel.add(testing);
    posPanel.add(checkbox);

    JPanel llpPanel = new JPanel();
    llpPanel.add(online);
    llpPanel.add(offline);
    llpPanel.add(status);
    llpPanel.add(reboot);
    llpPanel.add(account);
    llpPanel.add(amount);
    llpPanel.add(reset);
    llpPanel.add(approvordecl);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.add(initialize);
    buttonPanel.add(connect);
    buttonPanel.add(disconnect);
    buttonPanel.add(shutdown);
    buttonPanel.add(portsettings);
    frame.add(buttonPanel);
    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("LLP", null, llpPanel, "Low Level Protocol");
    tabbedPane.addTab("POS",null, posPanel, "Point Of Sale");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Test", null, testPanel, "Test");

    JPanel tabsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    tabsPanel.add(tabbedPane);
    frame.add(tabsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    frame.pack();



}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}






}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go for  `JTextArea`

A JTextArea is a multi-line area that displays plain text.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html

For required layout refer [**Layout Manager by Oracle**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: but how would I add it below all the buttons? I have tried to center it but it covers everything.